# Filter functions on list of product objects returns ony first match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress

I am working on a filter function for my e-commerce website.
We use Wordpress Headless CMS and get data via graphql to Gatsby, but this is more like a vanilla javascript problem I guess.

I have an array of strings holding brand names in a state
selectedBrand = [ "nike", "adidas", "puma" ]

The filter is meant to check string values in selectedBrand array and compare it with a value in an product object. Than return every object where the values match and dispatch them to a global state that hold the array of product objects.
Here is my component:

```
const ProductBrandsFilter = ({ brands, allProducts }) => {
  const [selectedBrand, setSelectedBrand] = React.useState([]);
  const { products } = React.useContext(GlobalStateContext);
  const dispatch = React.useContext(GlobalDispatchContext);

/** Helper function to save a list of string values in a state, useful for a list of checkboxes */
function handleCheckboxes(event, id, setState) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
    setState((value) => [...value, id]);
  } else {
    setState((value) => value.filter((it) => it !== id));
  }
}
React.useEffect(() => {
    let filter = [];
    products.map(
      (product) =>
        product.productBrands?.nodes.length > 0 &&
        product.productBrands.nodes.find((item) => {
          selectedBrand.includes(item.slug) && filter.push(product);
        })
    );
    selectedBrand.length > 0
      ? dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_PRODUCTS", value: filter })
      : dispatch({ type: "UPDATE_PRODUCTS", value: allProducts });
  }, [selectedBrand]);

  return (
    <BrandFilterWrapper>
      <h2>{_("Merke")}</h2>
      {brands.nodes.map((brand) => (
        <label htmlFor={brand.slug} key={brand.id}>
          <input
            type="checkbox"
            value={brand.slug}
            name={brand.slug}
            onChange={(e) => {
              handleCheckboxes(e, e.target.value, setSelectedBrand);
            }}
          />
          {brand.name}
        </label>
      ))}
    </BrandFilterWrapper>
  );
};

ProductBrandsFilter.propTypes = {
  brands: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
  allProducts: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object),
};

export default ProductBrandsFilter;
```

This is how the product object looks like:
[screenshot console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f1gPp.png)

Everything work fine except that I was expecting the product objects to add to the filter array for **every selected brand**, but it seems to work only if one brand is selected.